# Как заменить singleton? И нужно ли вообще

Tags: php, ооп, шаблон-одиночка

Нужен объект класса, доступ к которому можно получить из любой точки программы. При этом у класса должно быть единственное свойство $bot - которое является клиентом для управления чат-ботом. Сейчас это реализовано следующим образом:

> EventHandler.php

```
class EventHandler
{
    protected static Client $bot;

    private static $instance = null;

    private function __construct() { }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (self::$instance == null) {
            self::$instance = new EventHandler();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public static function init(Client $bot) {
        self::$bot = $bot;
    }
...
```

> index.php

```
        .....
$bot = new Client(BOT_TOKEN);
EventHandler::init($bot);

$bot->on(function (Update $update) use ($bot) {

    $event_handler = EventHandler::getInstance();
    $error = $event_handler->handle($update);
    
    .....
}
```

Comment: Правильно использовать шаблон DI, но начать можно с шаблона Service Locator

Comment: чем вас не устраивает текущая реализация? Если по сути вам нужен синглтон, то пишите синглтон. От того, получите вы экземпляр через статическое поле класса, или через сервис локатор, как предлагается. ничего в вашем использовании класса не изменится. Вопрос в том, не сам клиент у вас должен быть синглтоном то? зы: зачем `use($bot)` ?

Comment: Как я понял, в целом у меня всё правильно? Забыл добавить что использую библиотеку. Использование use($bot) из примера в документации.